# top down coldfusion webservice

Tags: coldfusion, wsdl

Is there is any possibility (special approach or wsdl2cfc utility) to generate web service (or it’s stub) with complex input output parameters and custom failure messages based on specified WSDL? I’ve read a lot of articles which describe how to consume that type of web services, but I haven’t found any article which describes how to implement them.

Comment: So you're wanting to create a web service according to a currently defined WSDL? Normally a WSDL defines the web service, not the other way around. I don't believe a component exists that does this, so you're going to have to read the WSDL, understand it, and create a component that matches it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can specify the WSDL a CFC presents with the [wsdlfile attribute](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_c_10.html), so you can certainly present an existing WSDL, if that's what you've got. Getting CF to map things properly when the service is invoked is another matter. I would start by taking the WSDL you have, making a CFC use it and implementing the right method names with no specified arguments and CFDUMPing the arguments structure to see what CF is getting.

You can do quite a lot to present the web service you want by using CFCs with the right names and CFPROPERTY tags in them. [You can also specify](http://tjordahl.blogspot.co.uk/2008/04/array-types-in-coldfusion-web-services.html) in a CFARGUMENT that the type="foo[]" and the generated WSDL will expect a list of FOO objects to be passed in.

I've no experience with returning custom errors through a web service, you may have to play with what CFTHROW does from within a web service

I assume you're trying to implement a service that already exists?

Comment: Not exactly. I have to integrate my company's system with some service. So I have to implement several specified SOAP web services. And I see that there is no any solution unless workarounds.